# Get last day of the month from a ZonedDateTime object

Tags: java, java-time, zoneddatetime, dayofmonth

I have previously been able to do this with Joda DateTime objects but i'm unsure how i can get the last day of a given month for a ZonedDateTime instance with a timezone applied.

e.g

- A leap year February return 29
- April returns 30.
- December returns 31.

With Jodatime i've used `dayOfMonth()` and `getMaximumValue()`, but how can I do the equivalent with **`ZonedDateTime`** in **Java 11**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't really need a ZonedDateTime object for that - a LocalDate is probably enough (unless you are dealing with exotic calendars).

```
val zdt = ZonedDateTime.now() //let's start with a ZonedDateTime if that's what you have
val date = zdt.toLocalDate() //but a LocalDate is enough
val endOfMonth = date.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth())
```

Note that you can also call `zdt.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth())` if you want to keep the time and timezone information.

Comment: Thanks, I was not familiar with TemporalAdjusters, but this worked well